# Как из Excel макросом (VBA) вызвать сетевое подключение

Tags: excel, макросы

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые гуру!
Существует в Excel некая база логинов (ячейка H) и паролей (ячейка I).
Периодически мне приходиться проверять их на работоспособность.

Для этого создано "Сетевое подключение" с помощью "мастер сетевого подключения" в котором были выбраны пункты -> "Подключить к интернет" далее -> "Установить подключение вручную" -> "Через высокоскоростное подключение запрашивающее имя пользователя и пароль". данное подключение названо - *test*.

Работаю по такому принципу... 
  1. Копирую логин сворачиваю Excel
  2. Вызываю сетевое подключение *test* вставляю логин.
  3. разворачиваю Excel копирую пароль сворачиваю Excel
  4. разворачиваю сетевое подключение *test* вставляю пароль нажимаю кнопку подключить
И вижу прошла ли авторизация.

Можно ли макросом VBA это данные операции автоматизировать? (разрывать сетевое подключения я буду в ручную) 
В интернете похоже никто еще такой задачей не задавался и думаю многим будет интересно. 
В макросах начал разбираться не давно и не имею большого опыта. 
Благодарю за внимание!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем все оказалось проще чем я думал :) 
Есть утилита rasdial она умеет запускать сетевое соединение.
Осталось только передавать ей значения логина и пароля. Вообщем код выглядит так

```
rasdial Test login pass
```

где:

```
Test - имя заранее созданного сетевого подключения PPPoE
login - логин пользователя
pass  - пароль пользователя
```

Ну а в моем случае это выглядит так:

```
Sub test()
  Shell "rasdial Test " + CStr(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 7).Value) + " " + CStr(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 8).Value), vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Благодарю всех за активность. Думаю в будущем этот топик кому нибудь да понадобиться

Answer (score 0):

А тебя решение задачи только в рамках VBA интересует?

Да, подобное вполне реально провернуть на VBA, но для этого нужно найти необходимые функции WinApi. Там есть функции поиска окна и компонентов, а так же придется повозится с UISpy, что бы увидеть дерево компонентов на окнах.

Нашел [пример](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/cs/windowsapisfromcs.aspx) только для C#, но основной смысл должен быть понятен и его можно перепилить под VBA:

```
int hwnd=0;
IntPtr hwndChild=IntPtr.Zero;

//Get a handle for the Calculator Application main window
hwnd=FindWindow(null,"Calculator");
if(hwnd == 0)
{
    if(MessageBox.Show("Couldn't find the calculator" + 
                       " application. Do you want to start it?", 
                       "TestWinAPI", 
                       MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)== DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Calc");
    }
}
else
{

    //Get a handle for the "1" button
    hwndChild = FindWindowEx((IntPtr)hwnd,IntPtr.Zero,"Button","1");

    //send BN_CLICKED message
    SendMessage((int)hwndChild,BN_CLICKED,0,IntPtr.Zero);

    //Get a handle for the "+" button
    hwndChild = FindWindowEx((IntPtr)hwnd,IntPtr.Zero,"Button","+");

    //send BN_CLICKED message
    SendMessage((int)hwndChild,BN_CLICKED,0,IntPtr.Zero);

    //Get a handle for the "2" button
    hwndChild = FindWindowEx((IntPtr)hwnd,IntPtr.Zero,"Button","2");

    //send BN_CLICKED message
    SendMessage((int)hwndChild,BN_CLICKED,0,IntPtr.Zero);

    //Get a handle for the "=" button
    hwndChild = FindWindowEx((IntPtr)hwnd,IntPtr.Zero,"Button","=");

    //send BN_CLICKED message
    SendMessage((int)hwndChild,BN_CLICKED,0,IntPtr.Zero);

}
```

Можно воспользоваться .NET, там есть [спец пространство](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx), которое может избавить от возни с WinApi.

Возможно, есть уже готовый софт, который может тебе помочь в этом деле.

Так же не исключаю, что в WinApi может присутствовать нужна тебе функция для проверки интернет соединения и тебе не придется ручками взаимодействовать с окном.

Comment: Ваш пример хорошо но я плохо владею С#
Знание С# у меня сеть но только самый начальный уровень... (( Но все равно спасибо за ответ. Интересует именно VBA так как база ведется в excel а писать новую базу на delphi пока не вижу целесообразности.